# Where to install WHMCS

Tags: cpanel, whmcs

Simple question: Where is the best place to install WHMCS?

Inside a control panel? (IE: cPanel) Or on a standalone server with nothing else installed?

Everything is hosted on aws, so provisioning servers isn't an issue. More interested if WHMCS is a resource hog and should be put on it's own.

Comment: Not sure which license you have but whmcs is usually activated per ip basis so changing ip in future might require reactivation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install WHMCS anywhere. There is no 'best place'. In terms of security, you may want to segregate your other services (such as DNS and email) that are often provisioned with a control panel, so personally I'd go for a blank server on which you install only the necessary services.

To comment on your question regarding WHMCS' resource usage: it isn't much of a resource hog. After all, it's just PHP. It's known to have a large database quickly, though, so you might want to keep that in mind when allocating resources.

Comment: Cool thanks. Pretty much what I was thinking. Also from a redundancy having it separate. Might just run it in cPanel for now, and separate it out later once it is more operational and use aws rds.

Comment: @Bradmage I'd do it the right way from the beginning. Oh. If my comment is helpful to you, please accept my answer :-).

Comment: Bah your so right. Taking short cuts now equals future pain.

Comment: I like the idea of separation. But installing whmcs on the root domain `example.com` on a separate server has made whm proxy domain not work... Which hindsight makes sense.

Comment: I'm thinking a hybrid, install all my own services on cp1.example.woo and client accounts on cp2, cp3, cp4... To make cPanel pay happy with its crazy proxies.

Comment: @Bradmage Segregating your internal infrastructure and your clients' is always a good idea.